# How to convert dictionary with numeric values to list based on how high the value is in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has some strings in it as keys and a number as value that serves as a ranking system, like for how important something is. Here is an example:

```py
{"eggs": 14, "milk": 8, "flowers":11, "couch":13}
```

I need a way to convert this into a list and ordering it based on their values so that the result would be:

```py
["eggs", "couch", "flowers", "milk"]
```

As you can see, the list order is based on the previous value that existed in the dictionary.
Is there something I can use for this?

Comment: have you made an attempt yourself?

Comment: @depperm yes i have tried to order the items in a for loop but my knowledge is still quite limited so i need some help with that if possible

Comment: please share you attempt in the question

Comment: @depperm i didn't really get anywhere with my attempts so I don't have anything to add to my questions. also i think this questions can be understood well without the need of a code example as it is a simple task (i hope)

Comment: when you ask on SO you should provide a [mcve] or your attempt as SO is not a coding service

Comment: @depperm oh sorry i just thought that wasn't a very difficult questions and i was quite lost. there are already some answers that help with my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a `key` argument to the built in sorted function as follows:

```
d = {"eggs": 14, "milk": 8, "flowers":11, "couch":13}
sorted(d, key=lambda k:d[k], reverse=True)
>> ['eggs', 'couch', 'flowers', 'milk']
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. this is what i was looking for!

Comment: Yep, I'm just waiting for SO to allow me to accept it as there needs to be some time from you answering the question to me accepting it. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sorted` function to sort the dict:

```
In [5]: d = {"eggs": 14, "milk": 8, "flowers":11, "couch":13}
In [8]: sorted(d, key=lambda x:d[x])                                                                                                                            
Out[8]: ['milk', 'flowers', 'couch', 'eggs']
```

in which the parameter `key` should be a function of which the input is the items of the set to sort, and the output is the value that represent the order.